# how to build a summary table without reshape

Tags: r

I have a df that looks like this:

[image]

it can be build using codes:

```
df<- structure(list(Gender = c("F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F"), Subject = c("M", 
"E", "E", "M", "M", "E")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Now I want to build a summary table for it. What is the best method to build one like this:

[image]

So far I have done:

```
tb1<-df %>% group_by(Gender, Subject)%>%
  summarise(total=n())

tb1w =tb1  %>% 
  spread(Subject, total)
```

Is there a better way to do it? just feel too many steps in order to get such simple table. Any suggestion on this? If I have to go this way, is it a better way to do it so I can get the table I want? such as better col names?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R option using `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(. ~ Gender, df, table)
  Gender Subject.E Subject.M
1      F         2         2
2      M         1         1
```

---

A `data.table` option using `dcast`

```
dcast(setDT(df), Gender ~ Subject)
```

which gives

```
   Gender E M
1:      F 2 2
2:      M 1 1
```

Comment: what if i need to filer out some data in `df`, how should i do that. OFr example, sth like `df %>% distinct (ID, Gender) %>% dcast(setDT(.), Gender ~ Subject)` this code doesn't work but might give you an idea what I want to do

Comment: @Stataq Could you give an example for "filter out some data"? What's is the desired output? I suggest you post a new question and provide detailed information.

Answer (score 3):

R has the table function for this application:

```
table(df)
```